# Grails: text instead of varchar

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I need the MySQL column type for the String field in my Domain class to be TEXT or VARCHAR(3000), but nothing I try seems to work - it remains VARCHAR(255). I've tried

```
static mapping = {
   longString type: 'text'
}
```

and

```
static mapping = {
   longString sqlType: 'text'
}
```

and

```
static constraints = {
   longString (blank: true, nullable: true, maxSize: 3000)
}
```

and

```
static constraints = {
   longString (blank: true, nullable: true, size: 0..65535)
}
```

MySQL Server version 5.0.95, Grails 2.4.3.
I'm totally mystified and would appreciate any help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the type of the column in the `mapping` block rather than `constraints`. Assuming the name of the property is `longString`, add this

```
static mapping = {
  longString type: 'text'
}
```

This will create a column with a MySQL type of `longtext`.

To verify that this works, try dropping your database, create a new (empty) database, restart the app and check the type of the column that is created. See [this example](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/blob/master/grails-app/domain/ie/festivals/Festival.groovy#L415) for reference.

Comment: but that's exactly the code that was cited in the question.

Comment: you really hit the spot! I completely forgot about dbCreate = "update" line in my configuration file. I dropped the db, and it all works now! Handface. Maybe you could edit your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I had a feeling that's what was happening :) I've edited my answer to include the verification info.